# Rails | How to Ignore raise error sidekiq worker | Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, capybara, sidekiq

I am pretty new to rails and my team recently moved to use sidekiq

Calling a worker with this instruction within model

```
CoolClassJob.perform_async(...)
```

I'm using a worker with a code similar to this:

```
class CoolClassJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "payment", retry: 5

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    10
  end

  def perform()
    ...
        whatever = {...}

        if whatever.status == 'successful'
          thisCoolFunction                  # successfully ends job
        elsif whatever.status == 'failed'
          anotherCoolFunction               # successfully ends job
        elsif whatever.pending?             # I want to retry if it falls in this condition since it is "waiting" for another task to complete.
          raise 'We are trying again'
        end
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

I tried with

```
          begin
            raise 'We are trying again!'
          rescue
             nil
          end
```

But when I run my tests, I get this error:

```
     Failure/Error: raise 'We are trying again!'
     
     RuntimeError:
       'We are trying again!'
     ...
```

Which of course, makes sense to me, since I'm raising the error, I tried searching but wasn't able to come up with a solution.
I'm wondering whether its able to a) `retry` again without raising an error or b) tell Capybara (rspec) to keep trying without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to reschedule your worker :

```rb
def perform()
    ...
        whatever = {...}

        if whatever.status == 'successful'
          thisCoolFunction                  # successfully ends job
        elsif whatever.status == 'failed'
          anotherCoolFunction               # successfully ends job
        elsif whatever.pending?             # I want to retry if it falls in this condition since it is "waiting" for another task to complete.
          self.class.perform_in(1.minute)
        end
    ...
end
```

Or maybe you can check this SO answer : [Sidekiq/Airbrake only post exception when retries extinguished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682594/sidekiq-airbrake-only-post-exception-when-retries-extinguished)

Comment: I guess with this I no longer need the `sidekiq_retry_in` part. 
Is this still affected by the number of retries I set? `sidekiq_options queue: "queue", retry: 5`

Comment: Also, for some reason I'm getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'perform_in' for CoolClassJob`

Comment: Yes you are right I updated to : `self.class.perform_in(1.minute)`